# Next view button in ScrollableView with Alloy

Tags: mobile, titanium-alloy

Hello everyone i have a very (it seems) simple problem, but its breaking my head in two. I don't know how can change the view(or page) within an ScrollableView with a button, I mean if i have this

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="win">
    <ScrollableView id="scrollableView" showPagingControl="true">
        <View id="view1" backgroundColor="#123">
           <Label>View 1</Label>
           <Button onClick="NextView">Next View</Button>
        </View>
        <View id="view2" backgroundColor="#246">
         <Label>View 2</Label>
         </View>
        <View id="view3" backgroundColor="#48b">
         <Label>View 3</Label>
         </View>
    </ScrollableView>
</Window>
```

I don't know what to put in the JS file of my Button, because i tried it almost all, I hope you can help me guys. Cheers

Comment: Please include the code you tried.